# Textfsm template for arp table output

Tags: python-textfsm

I'm Trying to create a template for the following out.  I don't get any matches when run through the textfsm parser but when using a regex tester it seems like it should work.

```
 Value PROTOCOL (\w+)
    Value IP_ADDRESS (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)
    Value HARDWARE_ADDRESS (\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+)
    Value INTERFACE (\w+\d+)

    Start
     ^\s+{PROTOCOL}\s+{IP_ADDRESS}\s+{HARDWARE_ADDRESS}\s+{INTERFACE}\s+ -> Record
```

Output:

```
IPV4 ARP Table
--------------
 Protocol    IP Address    Hardware Address   Interface  Age (min)
----------   ----------    ----------------   ---------  ---------
   Internet  10.13.68.113  24:be:05:28:10:71  vlan10     78
   Internet  10.13.68.114  b0:5a:da:38:7e:0d  vlan10     19
   Internet  10.13.68.117  10:e7:c6:05:d3:22  vlan10     62
   Internet  10.13.68.118  9c:eb:e8:75:0d:89  vlan10     1376
   Internet  10.13.68.119  70:5a:0f:d8:fc:cc  vlan10     65
   Internet  10.13.68.120  10:e7:c6:6e:6a:d2  vlan10     25
   Internet  10.13.68.121  80:ce:62:5e:c4:d1  vlan10     63
   Internet  10.13.68.123  10:e7:c6:6e:3a:fe  vlan10     12
   Internet  10.13.68.124  50:65:f3:1b:53:67  vlan10     46
   Internet  10.13.68.126  78:ac:c0:82:83:9c  vlan10     1376
   Internet  10.13.68.128  d4:95:24:ee:bd:d6  vlan10     1353
   Internet  10.13.68.150  78:f2:9e:90:f1:72  vlan10     1376*
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the correct regex and have post below with the output.

```
FSM Template: 
Value IP_ADDRESS (\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+) 
Value HARDWARE_ADDRESS (\w+.\w+.\w+.\w+.\w+.\w+) 
Value INTERFACE (\w+)

Start   ^\s+Internet\s+${IP_ADDRESS}\s+${HARDWARE_ADDRESS}\s+${INTERFACE} -> Record
```

Output:

```
FSM Table:
['IP_ADDRESS', 'HARDWARE_ADDRESS', 'INTERFACE']
['10.13.68.113', '24:be:05:28:10:71', 'vlan10']
['10.13.68.114', 'b0:5a:da:38:7e:0d', 'vlan10']
['10.13.68.117', '10:e7:c6:05:d3:22', 'vlan10']
['10.13.68.118', '9c:eb:e8:75:0d:89', 'vlan10']
['10.13.68.119', '70:5a:0f:d8:fc:cc', 'vlan10']
['10.13.68.120', '10:e7:c6:6e:6a:d2', 'vlan10']
['10.13.68.121', '80:ce:62:5e:c4:d1', 'vlan10']
['10.13.68.123', '10:e7:c6:6e:3a:fe', 'vlan10']
['10.13.68.124', '50:65:f3:1b:53:67', 'vlan10']
['10.13.68.126', '78:ac:c0:82:83:9c', 'vlan10']
['10.13.68.128', 'd4:95:24:ee:bd:d6', 'vlan10']
['10.13.68.150', '78:f2:9e:90:f1:72', 'vlan10']
```